# Does "good to see you" end a conversation?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I talked to a native English speaker today, and after a while, she abruptly said "good to see you" or something like this and went away. Does "good to see you" mean, instead of "good to see me", that she did not want to continue the conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've said this before. It's a polite way to end a conversation, whether it ends a conversation abruptly or not. As someone else just wrote, it means "It was nice to see you! But I need to get going." She just left off the last part, since that's kind of implied (if that's the right way to describe it) by her saying this.

Answer (score 6):

She probably meant **"It was good to see you, but I need to go."**

*"Good to see you"* can also be a greeting (*"It is good to see you."*). The words don't give any insight into why she wanted to end the conversation. It seems like she needed to end the conversation quickly and didn't want to be rude, but without more context it's difficult to say.